# How do I find the variance of $\hat\theta_\text{MLE}$ for $f_{\theta}(x) = \theta x^{\theta-1}$?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance

Given,

$$f_\theta(x) = \theta x^{\theta-1}, x \in [0,1], \theta >0$$

$$\hat\theta_\text{MLE} = \frac{-1}{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i)} $$

$$\operatorname{Var}(\hat\theta_\text{MLE}) = E_\theta(\hat\theta_\text{MLE}^2) - E_\theta(\hat\theta_\text{MLE})^2$$

How do I find the expectations, $E_\theta(\hat\theta_\text{MLE}^2)$ and $E_\theta(\hat\theta_\text{MLE})$,  given the presence of both summation and log in the denominator?

Comment: How did you find $\hat\theta_{\mathrm{MLE}}$? It would help to show what you've done so far.

Comment: Oh so I actually made a typo. It's supposed to be $f_\theta(x) = \theta x^{\theta-1}$ not $f_\theta(x) = \theta^xx^{\theta-1}$. I fixed the question to reflect the correct equation.

Comment: Ah, I should have caught on to that. The original expression did not integrate to one :)

Comment: I am not sure that this estimator has a finite mean, since 
$$
\mathbb E\left[\frac 1{\log X_1}\right] = \int_0^1 \frac1{\log x} \theta x^{\theta-1}\ \mathsf dx
$$
which does not converge.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/335087/119261. Possibly also asked here before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$f_X(x) = \theta x^{\theta-1},$$ then $Y = -\log X$ has density $$f_Y(y) = f_X(e^{-y}) e^y = \theta e^{-(\theta-1)y} e^y = \theta e^{-\theta y}, \quad y > 0.$$  Consequently $Y \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\theta)$, and $$W = -\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n,\theta)$$ with density $$f_W(w) = \frac{\theta^n w^{n-1} e^{-\theta w}}{\Gamma(n)}.$$  It follows that $\hat\theta_{\text{MLE}} = n/W$ has density $$f_{\hat \theta}(z) = f_W(n/z)\left|\frac{d}{dz}\left[\frac{n}{z}\right]\right| = \frac{n}{z^2} \frac{\theta^n (n/z)^{n-1} e^{-\theta n/z}}{\Gamma(n)} = \frac{(n\theta)^n e^{-(n\theta)/z}}{z^{n+1} \Gamma(n)}$$ which implies $$\hat \theta_{\text{MLE}} \sim \operatorname{InverseGamma}(n,n\theta).$$  I leave as an exercise to the reader to show that $$\operatorname{Var}[\hat \theta_{\text{MLE}}] = \frac{(n\theta)^2}{(n-1)^2 (n-2)}, \quad n > 2.$$